# Retrieve index column

Tags: sqlite

I have this index schema: `CREATE index comments_idx ON comments (books)`

How can I retrieve column name ("books") through SQL query?

Comment: You already know the name of the column (i.e. "books"). What exactly are you asking?

Comment: How to get it programatically (i.e. with sql query). `SELECT * FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='index'` gives me the indexes, but I further need columns referenced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_index_info) says:

> **PRAGMA index_info(***index-name***);**
>
> This pragma returns one row each column in the named index. The first column of the result is the rank of the column within the index. The second column of the result is the rank of the column within the table. The third column of output is the name of the column being indexed.

```
> pragma index_info(comments_idx);
seqno       cid         name      
----------  ----------  ----------
0           0           books
```